# How to create recursive download and rename bash script

Tags: terminal, finder, command-line, bash

I need to make a bash script that will download a image with curl and then rename the file, wait 5 mins and then re-download the file and rename it again so that the new file does not replace the old file. I understand the wait and curl download part but I cant make the script recursively rename the new files. It would need to rename the files like: latest.jpg --> latest1.jpg and then the next one latest.jpg --> latest2.jpg. Please help!

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    curl -O link.com/latest.jpg
    let "i++"
    mv latest.jpg $ilatest.jpg
    sleep 5m
done
```

Comment: I dont know what to try. How would I make the script add a number to the name. Ive tried $ and then let "i++" $i and that didnt work.

Comment: Please edit your original post with the shell code that you tried to use.

Comment: ok I added what I tried

Comment: Do you need the existing files, or do you just want to incrementally add a number to each new file you download?

Comment: I want to incrementally add a number to each new file i donwload

Comment: `$ilatest.jpg` is being interpreted as a variable called "ilatest", i.e. `${ilatest}.jpg`. Since you have no such variable, every 5 min this is downloading latest.jpg and renaming it to ".jpg" (which by default is a hidden file. Use `ls -a` to see it). As per the answer below, use `${i}latest.jpg` to delimit your variable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change two things to make it work

- the variable need to be put in `{}` to separate it from the other text (how should bash know that the variable isn't called `ilatest` otherwise?
- `sleep` expects the sleep time in seconds

This gives you

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while true
do
    curl -O link.com/latest.jpg
    let "i++"
    mv latest.jpg latest-${i}.jpg
    sleep $((5*60))
done
```

In addition, having the `sleep` as part of the loop code will require that you press ^C twice to terminate the loop. You might want to try the following instead

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
s=0
while sleep $s
do
    curl -O link.com/latest.jpg
    let "i++"
    mv latest.jpg latest-${i}.jpg
    let 's=5*60'
done
```

Answer (score -2):

I would do this as one-liner just saving file to a new location. Can't see any reason to move files around.

```sh
i=0; while :; do curl link.com/latest.jpg -o ${i}_latest.jpg && sleep $(( 5 * 60 )) && (( i++ )); done
```

I suppose this script takes long time to run and to be able to close terminal or logout suggest to use [nohup](https://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/) command